# Swift Unit test - Wait until service response

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xcode6, xctest

I'm try make the Unit Test from my app. My app include service integration. I'm implementing an Adapter for this task and I need wait the service response for process the response and then validate the response object.

I have 2 delegate function that are called when the service response arrive.

```
 func didReceiveAPIResults(#results: AnyObject, path: String, serverTag: String) 


 func didReceiveAPIResultsFailed(#error: NSError, errorObject: AnyObject, path: String, serverTag: String)
```

I need process the response in the previous functions and then finish the Unit Test.

How I can specify this?

Answer (score -1):

A test which depends on an external API is not much of a "unit" test. It may be more reliably to implement a test double for your adapter to return a consistent response. Such a double might then be able to provide a synchronous interface by calling your delegate methods immediately.

If you really need to test asynchronous behavior XCTest provides `XCTestExpectation` for [Writing Tests of Asynchronous Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/testing_3_writing_test_classes/testing_3_writing_test_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH4-SW6). Most third party testing libraries provide something similar as well.

Comment: I understand your point but I need test all app integration. I need test the app fluid, simulate buttons touch, etc.

Comment: You can test all the app's functionality even better when the service response is mocked in multiple ways to simulate different behaviors depending on the response's result. Your integration (!) tests will run much longer and they will break much more often when the response differs because of real data.

Comment: Sorry, that page cannot be found :(